# Tapestry validation on disabled field

Tags: java, forms, tapestry

I basically have a textfield which may not be empty, so I added this validation:

```
t:validate="required"
```

(I actually have a few more validation criteria but they aren't relevant here). However, this field can also sometimes be disabled (it is bound to a property in the Java code):

```
t:disabled="isFieldADisabled"
```

Additionally the value is bound to a property:

```
t:value="entity.fieldA"
```

It's designed so that the property is never empty when the field is disabled. However, when the field is disabled, I can't submit the form - even though there's something displayed in the textbox. I don't know what's going on here, but I then tried to [manually](http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html) validate, like that:

```
@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALIDATE)
void onValidate(){
    if (isFieldADisabled)
        // What should I do here?
}
```

As my comment points out, I'm not sure what to do in there. As an additional complication this whole thing is in a `container`, which itself is contained in a `form` - so I don't really have access to the form itself from the `onValidate` method.

I suspect this is a general issue, if it's not please let me know whether you need more information.

**EDIT** I have evaluated the state of the textfield in `onPrepareForSubmitFromEditForm`:

[image]

As you can see the field is indeed disabled and its value is not even empty. However in `onValidateFromEditForm` tge value for `disabled` is actually false, but the value for the field still is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your component is inside a form you can use one of the built-in [environmental services](http://tapestry.apache.org/environmental-services.html) available to components during rendering/form submission, i.e. [ValidationTracker](https://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ValidationTracker.html). Using the service it's possible to record form validation errors manually, i.e. `ValiadationTracker#recordError(Field field, String message)`.

Such components won't receive the `VALIDATE` event by default though, as this event is triggered on the `Form` component itself and bubbles up to its containers. This event is used for cross-form validation, when you need to implement custom validation for multiple fields. You can still use `ValidationTracker` to record validation errors.

As for the [`disabled` property of `AbstractField`](https://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/base/AbstractField.html#disabled), if its value is `true` the component won't participate in validation, neither client-side, nor server-side:

> If true, then the field will render out with a disabled attribute (to turn off client-side behavior). When the form is submitted, the bound value is evaluated again and, if true, the field's value is ignored (not even validated) and the component's events are not fired.

Comment: The last part doesn't make much sense though - the form definitely doesn't validate and a message pops up that the disabled fields have to be filled

Comment: Is it a server-side or client-side validation error? For client-side I'd double check that corresponding DOM element has `disabled=""` attribute, and for the server-side that parameter is actually `true` on submit, maybe try to set a breakpoint inside `AbstractField#processSubmission() { if (!disabled) processSubmission(controlName); }` and check what's the actual returned value of the `disabled` field

Comment: It turns out the property disabled was mapped to did indeed change just before validation (I have no idea why). I managed to fix this problem anyway - but the disabled fields definitely weren't empty until the end and now, if the disabled fields would have no value anyway it still doesn't validate

Comment: what you see in the `disabled` field under debugger is not a real value -- it's a shallow copy (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-1208), it's updated only after actual read from parameter binding